# Есть ли конвертер html приложений в android приложение?

Tags: javascript, android, html, apk

Интересует возможность конвертации html-приложений в apk. Есть ли такие конверторы ?

Comment: какая-нибудь [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)

Comment: Cordova, ionic, Phonegap, angular все одно и тоже, сразу предупрежу что не все так гладко как кажется, просто читалку rest  можно сделать за 5 минут, а вот сбор каких то данных например о состоянии батареи придется делать через плагины. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ru/5.0.0/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html